Nodejs route works in production but throws 404 in local
https://eogmap.mines.edu/giree/layers/vnf2022/3/3/3.mvt
The above url is pointing to the production environment and works perfectly fine by returing the response.
http://localhost:8000/giree/layers/vnf2022/3/3/3.mvt
The same url throws 404 not found error through local server, I am not able to understand how the previous developers handled this.
http://localhost:8000/
http://localhost:8000/dashboard
http://localhost:8000/backgrounds
http://localhost:8000/layers
These above 4 routes returns the index.html file of build folder with 200 status
app.js
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'development':
    app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../build')));
    app.use('/dashboard', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../build')));
    app.use('/backgrounds', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../build')));
    app.use('/layers', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../build')));
    break;
  default:
    app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use('/dashboard', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use('/backgrounds', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use('/layers', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
    break;
}

I expect the same response as the production URL since I'm pointing to the same database that the production URL is using, and I'm certain the database is connected.
